# Child Context - Deleting Object Without Save?

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm creating a `recipe` object inside of a child context. I'm adding `ingredients`, which are a relational object to `recipe`.

```
lazy var childRecipe: Recipe = { return Recipe(context: self.childContext) }()
let newIngredient = Ingredient(context: self.childContext)
newIngredient.parent = childRecipe
newIngredient.percentage = 0.0
```

I'm trying to figure out how to remove/delete an ingredient that's already connected to `childRecipe`. This is what I've tried, but it's not working.

```
var ingredients = getIngredients()
let ingredientToDelete = ingredients[indexPath.row]
self.childContext.delete(ingredientToDelete)
```

I believe this isn't working because the context isn't being saved. But my problem is that I'm not ready to save. I just want to remove the ingredient that's not needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My `cellForRowAt` method had a section that taps into `Recipe` and gets it's relational `Ingredient` objects for display.

Turns out what I needed to do was remove the parent relation of `Ingredient` to `Recipe`. Which then allowed the section to return the correct number of rows. This then allowed the `ingredientToDelete` to be marked for delation without issue.

```
let ingredientToDelete = ingredients[indexPath.row]
newIngredient.parent = nil
self.childContext.delete(ingredientToDelete)
```